# Angular - Module federation with webcomponents and urls in manifest

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-module-federation

I'm trying to load a Micro Frontend as a webcomponent, following this tutorial from [angulararchitects](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/multi-framework-and-version-micro-frontends-with-module-federation-your-4-steps-guide/).

Configuration in my Shell app :

**main.ts**

```
initFederation('/appconf/mf.manifest.json')
.catch(err => console.error(err))
.then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
bootstrap(AppModule, {
  production: false,
  appType: 'shell'
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));;
```

**app-routing.module.ts** : working

```
 {
    matcher: startsWith('mfe1'),
    component: WebComponentWrapper,
    data: {
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js', 
        exposedModule: './web-component',
        elementName: 'app-mfe1'
    } as WebComponentWrapperOptions
 },
```

**app-routing.module.ts** : not working

```
{
    matcher: startsWith('mfe1'),
    component: WebComponentWrapper,
    data: {
        type: 'manifest',
        remoteName: 'mfe1',
        exposedModule: './web-component',
        elementName: 'app-mfe1'
    } as WebComponentWrapperOptions
}
```

My manifest is loaded (I can see it in the network tab).

But I have the following error with this configuration (type 'manifest'):

> Manifest does not contain mfe1

**mf.manifest.json**

```
{
 "mfe1": {
  "remoteEntry": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"
 }
}
```

Do you know the syntaxe to use a webcomponent with a manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

the JSON file and main.ts are wrong.

```
// main.ts
import { loadManifest } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';

loadManifest('/appconf/mf.manifest.json') // you can use a remote too like 'http://localhost:2200/manifest'
.catch(err => console.error(err))
.then(() => import('./bootstrap'))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

the right JSON is this one:
`{"mfe1": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"}`